# Reading a string with commas gets automatically wrapped with quotes

Tags: csv, groovy

I am parsing a tab delimited file and some of the columns contain commas in them.
Each column with a comma is getting wrapped with quotes , which breaks some code later on that tries to search for those values (without the quotes). For example if the original value in the csv file was "A, B, C" it is now stored as ""A, B, C"".

How can those extra quotes be removed/escaped automatically?

Thanks

The code I am using to read the file is:

```
genresMap = [:] 
new File(runtime_dir + 'file.csv').eachLine {
    def line -> column = line.split("\t");
    genresMap[column[0].toString()] = column[1];
}
```

Comment: can you post a bit of your csv file?

Comment: Your CSV file probably has the quotes around the values, else the commas would be interpreted as a column separation. Use a text editor to see what the CSV file looks like. You should use a real CSV library to read CSV, instead of splitting lines. The library would take care of those quotes for you.

Comment: Supercsv is a good fast Java library for parsing CSV files. It takes care of quotes, multiple lines, etc. http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, that was indeed the problem. The quotes were visible in a text editor but not in the CSV viewer.